# How to detect specific elements with MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am learning about MutationObserver and how to check for added elements, I am trying to extend how to detect when an element with a specific id is added to the page:

I thought this code should detect some element with id #sections but it is not detecting:

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
        mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
            mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
                if (node.id === "sections") {
                    console.log(node);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
    });
```

now this code detects #sections, but detects it always has a mutation, so I had to add a check:

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            const sections = document.querySelector("#sections");
            if (!sections.classList.contains("added")) {
                console.log(sections);
                sections.classList.add("added");
                // observer.disconnect();
            }
        });
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, {
        childList: true,
    });
```

How can I detect in the right way some specific element?

I thought the first code should work to detect the element but it doesn't, the second one detects each mutation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, the observer target should be the parent of the `specific-elements`,
and check the mutation props `removedNodes`  if there has the element you needed.
sample code below:
see the console

```html
<body>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  <button onclick="removeNode()">rm</button>

  <div id="sideNav" class="sideNav">

  </div>
  <script>
    // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
    const targetNode = document.getElementById("sideNav").parentNode;

    // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
    const config = { childList: true, subtree: false };

    // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
    const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
      console.log('object :>> ', mutationList, observer);
      for (const mutation of mutationList) {
        if (mutation.type === "childList") {
          console.log("A child node has been added or removed.");
        }
      }
    };

    // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

    // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
    observer.observe(targetNode, config);

    // Later, you can stop observing
    // observer.disconnect();

    function removeNode() {
      document.getElementById('sideNav').remove()
    }
  </script>
</body>
```